# Cannot instantiate a POJO with jackson 3+ with builder pattern

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Article.Builder.class)
public class Article {

    private final String id;
    private final String headline;

    private Article(final Builder builder) {
        this.id = checkNotNull(builder.id);
        this.headline = checkNotNull(builder.headline);
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {
        private String id;
        private String headline;

        public Builder id(final String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder headline(final String headline) {
            this.headline = headline;
            return this;
        }

        public Article build() {
            return new Article(this);
        }
    }

}
```

With these annotation I can serialize and deserialize the object using the Jackson ObjectMapper, but I receive an error when using Article in the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article/{category}", method = PUT)
public void receiveArticle(@PathVariable("category") final String category, final Article article) {
    service.createOrUpdateArticle(category, article);
}
```

calling it with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/article/cat_1/?article={"id":"aid001","headline":"this is the headline"}
```

this is the error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.Article]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Article.<init>()

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Article.<init>()
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
...
```

I followed this tutorial to use the Builder Pattern: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern

Anybody have an idea why I get this error?

Comment: Please don't put JSON as a query parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring will not use JSON deserialization to produce an argument for your handler method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article/{category}", method = PUT)
public void receiveArticle(@PathVariable("category") final String category, final Article article) {
    service.createOrUpdateArticle(category, article);
}
```

The way you currently have it, the `Article` parameter is interpreted as a model attribute, as if it was annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. Spring will try to use a parameterless constructor to instantiate the class. Since your `Article` class doesn't provide one, it fails.

Instead, move the JSON to the body of the request, send a `Content-Type: application/json` header in the request, and annotate your parameter with  `@RequestBody`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article/{category}", method = PUT)
public void receiveArticle(@PathVariable("category") final String category, @RequestBody final Article article) {
    service.createOrUpdateArticle(category, article);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The build() method must be placed in your `Builder` class and you have it in the `Article` class